# How to input the value 'NULL' into nvarchar column in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a requirement to insert the literal value 'NULL' into a nvarchar column as a default value. But when I insert records the default is going as db NULL instead of the literal 'NULL'. Can someone tell me where I am going wrong?

Comment: Incidentally, what is the purpose of defaulting a column to `'NULL'` instead of `NULL`? This sounds like a questionable decision to me.

Comment: @djacobson - The requirement for us to send 'NULL' is because the data we send it out is consumed by another application which needs to see the text NULL rather than an empty tag.

Comment: Ah well, what can you do? Fair enough. :S

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So you want the actual string of "NULL" to be inserted?  Try something like this:

```
create table NullTable
(
    nvarchar(100) not null default 'NULL',
    .... -- your other fields
)
```

**EDIT:**  *Here is a full solution*

```
create table InsertNull
(
    Nullfield nvarchar(100) not null default 'NULL',
    someint int not null
)
go

insert into insertnull(someint)
select 20

select *
from InsertNull
```

Comment: shark- I do have a table with the same setup. In the same example say our table contains two fields field1 with default of 'NULL', field2 INT.  if I run the query say - insert into nulltable (field1) select 20 then field1 is still showing as NULL DB value

Comment: @VKarthik check out my edit.  I just ran this and it is showing the string 'NULL' on the result query.

Comment: @VKarthik are you looking to have the single quotes stored in the column too? Because what Shark has will have the default of a string NULL not DB `NULL`.

Answer (score 3):

Note the quotes:

```
INSERT INTO yourtable (varcharfield) VALUES ('NULL'); // string null
INSERT INTO yourtable (varcharfield) VALUES (NULL); // actual null
```

Comment: I think the OP wants the default value of the field to be the string 'NULL', not just inserting the value on an `INSERT` statement.

Answer (score 1):

If set the default in code instead of the designer is should work.

```
ALTER TABLE [myTable] ADD  DEFAULT ('NULL') FOR [TextColumn]
```